# need to do VERSUS need for doing

Tags: verb-usage

I know "need to do" is correct.

> I need to read this article.

Sometimes I come across "need for doing"

> I see no need for doing it.

Incidentally, I wonder if "need for doing" is passable.

> There is no need to pay for it.
>
> There is no need for paying for it.

Are both correct?

Comment: "There is no need for paying." where paying is a gerund.  "for paying for it" would be a mistake. However, no need for playing it. [a piece of music]. Again, that is a gerund phrase.

Comment: So much effort by me for nothing, I see.

Answer (score 0):

"There is no need for paying." where **paying is a gerund**. "*There is no need for paying for it*" would be a mistake or at best very awkward. Because *what is meant in saying that is really*: ***There is no need to pay for it.*** With a bare infinitive.

However, no need for playing it. [a piece of music]. Again, that is a gerund phrase. Like these: **Playing it** is always fun. **Paying the price** is difficult.

**No need for + gerund or gerund phrase**. For example: **No need for paying the price. No need for making a fuss. No need for paying.**

VERSUS

**No need to + bare infinitive for x**: **No need to pay for it. No need to play it. No need to pay for them**. Where the verb after to is a bare infinitive.

Comment: I don't understand where you are getting at in your musings. Is it a legit construction or not? If yes. What are the guidelines?

Comment: @user1425 Musings, not. Explanations. "There is no need for paying for it" is wrong because **what is meant by that** is: There is no need to pay for it. Paying for it is a gerund. Paying for it was expensive.

Comment: What about these examples of yours "No need for paying the price. No need for making a fuss. No need for paying."? They are not complete sentences. How can they be used?

Comment: @user1425 That is to show you  how to use a gerund. They can all be preceded by: "There is" to make full sentences.

Comment: But you said ""There is no need for paying for it" would be a mistake or at best very awkward." So, how can "there is No need for paying the price. No need for making a fuss. No need for paying." be justified?

Comment: @user1425 I think I have explained this enough. *There is no need for paying for it* is idiomatically: There is no need **to pay for it**.

Comment: In what sentence did you explain it? You said this: ""There is no need for paying for it" would be a mistake or at best very awkward." So, I take it that "no need for paying" is wrong. Then you give these:"No need for paying the price. No need for making a fuss. No need for paying." You don't mention that they are wrong. I wish you could understand how misleading it is.

Comment: "There is no need for paying." is **right**.  For example: There is no need for paying. The service is free. There is no need to pay **for it**. The service is free.  And also: to pay [direct object]: pay the price, like make [direct object] a fuss.